# Can i connect parallel ble devices with a bluetooth 4.0 adapter, and recieve the notifications simulataneously from all of them?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to know that whether i can connect multiple BLE Devices in parallel with a single **Tp-link 4.0 adpater (bluetooth)**. My current focus is to get this scenario working in C# in Windows. If it could be done, then please tell me how to do this. And if not, then is there a **need to switch the OS** or the **programming language (maybe javascript or python).**

**I have got many examples that connect one device at a time, but I am sure that bluetooth supports multiple connections in parallel. So, please guide me how to do this.
The script will also be provided, if someone needs it.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can. How many - depends on your hardware. I can show how to do that with our Bluetooth Framework. Here is the link: https://github.com/btframework/ConcurrentBleConnections  Also take a look on out WeDo imp,ementation that also can connect to few LEGO Hubs: https://github.com/btframework/WeDo/tree/master/NET%20Edition/WeDo%20Framework

Comment: Thanks for the help!. My use case is that I need to this on Windows, using a single 4.0 adapter. So, is there any resource that helps me get started.

Comment: I just need to connect five wearables in parallel for about an hour and get notifications from all of them.

Comment: The code I reffered to is for Windows and uses single Bluetooth 4.0 adapter.

Comment: May I know why wcl references gives error

Comment: The lib is not included. You can downlaod it from btframework.com

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me that whether it is possible with bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher to have multiple clients in parallel..

Comment: bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher can not have ANY clients. All it can do is just listen for advertisements. Nothing more.

Comment: But, I am able to get two ble devices connected and get notifications from them in parallel. But the thing is that when i try to connect the third, some sort of errors arise in code. Also, I need to have 5 devices in parallel, but i have not been successful at that

Comment: Once again. BluetoothLeAdvertisementWatcher (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher?view=winrt-20348) does not even have any Connect method. It is not possible to connect to any device with BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.